# Wiring BLTouch V3.1 on Anet A6 and the JST connector polarity

Tags: bltouch, anet-a6

I have looked at many tutorials already but I am not sure about how I should wire this properly. I bought a BLTouch V3.1 together with an extension cable

[image]

Now, the thing is, with that extension cable you get one set of wires for the servo in a Dupont connection (brown, red, yellow) and one for the Z-min in a JST connection (black, white).

The JST connection actually has room for three cables, and when holding it the way you can plug it into the Anet A6 you have the following order: Empty, Black, White. However, IIRC the input Z-min input on the Anet wants the following order: GND, VCC, Z-min.

So if I would use the cable like this. then I would connect the black wire of the BLTouch to the VCC. Will this cause any trouble with my BLtouch?
Because I think it does, but then again, why would you sell such a wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black is GND and should not be connected to VCC.

Note that you can simply pop out the metal parts (use a pin to press a small clip) from the connector and rearrange how you want them to be.

Note that most printer controller boards have the GND of all the endstops connected, so technically you don't need the black wire at all. I make my own extension cables (from 4 wire cable) where the brown and black are connected at the sensor side and a single white wire is used for the Z-min endstop.

Comment: Great, thanks for the confirmation. Didnt knew how easy it was to re-arrange the wires in the JST connector!